# Extracting Tables in Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word

I have a Word document with captions on tables, and the tables have cheat sheet values. How to create a macro that detects all tables (`ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(Referencetype:="Table")`), and transfer the tables into a new document?
The MS Word documencation nor the autocomplete were helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This procedure copies all tables from the active document and pastes into a new document:

```
Sub CopyAllTablesToNewDoc()

    Dim docSource As Document
    Dim docDest As Document
    Dim tbl As Table

    Set docSource = ActiveDocument
    Set docDest = Documents.Add

    For Each tbl In docSource.Tables
        tbl.Range.Copy
        docDest.Paragraphs(docDest.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Paste
        docDest.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
    Next tbl

End Sub
```

Note: it does not copy the table captions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to tell you a secret. docx files are essentially renamed zip files with some xml mixed in to handle asset placement.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa982683%28v=office.12%29.aspx

I've never tried to handle it myself, but with enough poking around with zip and xml you should find what you need.